# How to do Ipad pagination

Tags: ios, ipad, pagination

My project is a news application, the news are came from the url by using xml parsing, my problem is news content are big which cannot display in a single page, I want to display the content in multiple pages according to the size of the content dynamically. The user can navigate by paging and see the rest of the content. I want to do it in ipad.

Comment: the problm is  i want to show the pages dynamically according to the size of the url content

Comment: Now that is more like a question. Please edit your question to include the comment.

Comment: Guys please the comment first that is the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is divide your string or data into parts as per your requirement.

Go through the documentation of [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to divide it.
.

If you are successful in doing so than you will get the no. of pages that is required to show in the scroll view.

You can set the contentSize of scrollview like this.

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(scrollView.frame.width * noOfPages, scrollView.frame.height);
```

Then just enable paging for scrollview.

Also if you are using pageControl to show the no. of pages then you just need to set the number of pages for the same and everything will be taken care off.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UIScrollView` class to hold the content and turn on its `pagingEnabled` property to simulate pagination.

You can see the docs for [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Comment: ok,but i want to show the pages dynamically according to the size of the url content